# How do I install bitwig?

Tags: package-management

Here are the install commands I entered. Why is this not working?

`$ sudo apt install bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb'
```

`$ sudo apt install bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb'
```

`$ sudo apt install /bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb`

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file /bitwig-studio-3.3.11.deb given on commandline'
```

Comment: You need to be either in the folder where the file is and use **./whatever.deb** or use the full path. And if you don't mind please post your questions respectfully, i.e., by respecting the language and its formal usages so no "???" or "WTF" and code should be posted with code tags (go advanced, press "#" and paste inside).

Comment: i had help from another bitwig member, it was me not seeing the difference between a dash and a period.  i never wanted to be a programmer, here I am learning command line because i'm just done with microsoft and apple....  THANK YOU!

Comment: another user help me see i putting a - where a . is needed, that's why it failed to install, user error, of course.  1000% newb here...

Comment: FILE NOT SUPPORTED

when I try double click and open with software installer.  Ubuntu installer opens and gives pop up message: FILE NOT SUPPORTED

but I installed it "manually" so why the pop up message?  it's a .deb directly from bitwig, should double click install no problem?

Comment: If you are still having problems, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352330/edit) your question and include details.  If you are getting errors after using the correct command, you should include the exact output verbatim and unredacted.  Don't forget to use formatting as explained above.

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is incorrect.

If you downloaded a `.deb` from the internet and you wish to install it with `apt`, you must `cd` to the directory where the `.deb` file is located.

Then you need to run `sudo apt install ./yourdebfile.deb`.

You should run `sudo apt update` before any other commands in `apt` to make sure that your package manager is up-to-date with the most current list of software.  Otherwise you can encounter dependency issues.

Note that the `.` must go before the `/`.

Comment: You could also just double click the .deb file and then it will install (if you want to do it in a graphical user interface way). Very good answer though.